# Xdebug on Synology NAS

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug, nas

Xdebug section appears in the `phpinfo()`, so I guess it's already installed on the NAS.

```text
Version 3.1.2
Development Helpers ✔ enabled
Coverage    ✘ disabled
GC Stats    ✘ disabled
Profiler    ✘ disabled
Step Debugger   ✘ disabled
Tracing ✘ disabled
xdebug.client_host  localhost
xdebug.client_port  9003
```

**How can I enable and configure the step debugger, to be able to debug PHP on VSCode?**

---

##### UPDATE

So, I have advanced, but still not solved...

DSM version: 7.2-64570 Update 1

In **Web Station** under **Script Language Service** I created a new PHP profile (Dev Xdebug), and under the **Core** tab I could set Xdebug settings according to the settings I have in my XAMPP php.ini:

```ini
xdebug.mode = develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9003
```

Then in **Web Service** I changed the **profile** of my web service to Dev Xdebug.

Then opening the website in and dumping `phpinfo()` shows both Development Helpers and Step Debugging enabled, but VSCode still ignores breakpoints.

Adding to **Listen for Xdebug** `"hostname": "localhost"` starts debugging, but ignores breakpoints. `"hostname": "<NAS_Name>"` and `"hostname": "<IP_address>"` result with the error:

> listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available IP_Address:Port#

when trying to start debugging, even though the IP_Address is the correct one of my NAS. Disabling firewall on my PC and on the NAS didn't help.

In VSCode `launch.json` has the following configuration:

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for Xdebug", 
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 0,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
        ],
        "env": {
            "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
            "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
            "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
            "-S",
            "localhost:0"
        ],
        "program": "",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "port": 9003,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
            "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
            "action": "openExternally"
        }
    }
]
```

I'm open for other ideas.

Comment: 1) It's Xdebug that connects to the debug client (VSCode in this case) and NOT other way around. 2) It's VSCode that listens on Xdebug port.

Comment: *"Adding to **Listen for Xdebug** `"hostname": "localhost"` starts debugging, but ignores breakpoints. `"hostname": "<NAS_Name>"` and `"hostname": "<IP_address>"` result with the error"* That is expected outcome. From the Xdebug for VSCode docs: "`hostname`: The address to bind to when listening for Xdebug". You cannot listen on NAS IPs (simply because it "belongs" to / used by another device and not your PC). Just use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` should be used here in almost all cases.

Comment: *" I could set Xdebug settings according to the settings I have in my XAMPP php.ini:"* That great // a move in the right direction. yet, it misses on point -- `xdebug.client_host`. By default it uses `localhost` .. and it's fine to omit it for local XAMPP ... but you have Xdebug on another device/NAS...  In this case it should point to the IP machine when debug client (VSCode) is running (as need from the NAS) -- see my #1 in my first comment. So .. find out the IP of your actual PC and use it. Using `xdebug.discover_client_host = true` should also do the job (depends on your network ofc)

Comment: If still having issues: 1) run a simple PHP page with calling `xdebug_info();` and show the full output. It will list the current live config parameters so you can see what was applied and what not etc. 2) Enable Xdebug logging and try to debug -- the Xdebug log fill will show where it tries to connect to and what the response is. If it's empty -- check the path (must point to the file and the file must be writable) or Xdebug does not see the "debug me" flag (can force the debug with `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` if so desired).

Comment: Thank you LazyOne for your input.
I have done the following:
xdebug.client_host = My Pc IP address
xdebug.discover_client_host = true
in launch.json "hostname": "localhost"
this results with the following errors on the xdebug_info() output under Diagnostic Log > Message:
[Step Debug] Creating socket for '192.168.123.11:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).

Comment: [Step Debug] Could not connect to client host discovered through HTTP headers, connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.123.11:9003. :-|
[Step Debug] Creating socket for '192.168.123.11:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29). 
[Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 192.168.123.11:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), 192.168.123.11:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

Comment: You can set `xdebug.xxx` settings in VSCode's `launch.json` (I assume you mean `"runtimeArgs"` section). .. but it will be used for local PHP servers only (like PHP's own built-in web serve). You cannot influence remote web server this way. For remote systems better do those changes in remote php.ini (on your NAS).

Comment: Changing "hostname" to my PC IP address, resolves all those errors, but still breakpoints are being changed to unverified breakpoints on page refresh and of course ignored.

Comment: *"'192.168.123.11:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress"* 1) Firewall? 2) Nobody listens on that IP/port (check with `netstat -abn` on Windows); 3) Wrong IP?

Comment: *"but still breakpoints are being changed to unverified breakpoints on page refresh and of course ignored."* Must be path mapping -- VSCode must know how to translate local path into the remote (as Xdebug works on remote .. so it uses their local (your remote) paths). https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug -- check "Remote Host Debugging" section, `pathMappings`

Comment: I do not know how to access and edit the php.ini on the NAS, but all changes I do through the Web Station's Core variables are being displayed in the phpinfo() and xdebug_info outputs.
192.168.123.11:9003 does not appear in the `code` netstat -abn `code` output and for the test, both PC and NAS firewalls and disabled. PC IP is correct and static.
I tried setting the `code` pathMappings `code` without any success, but I'm not sure I set them correctly. `code` "/volume1/web": "${workspaceFolder}/www" `code` (/volume1/web is projects location) adding `code` /<project_name>`code` did not help.

Comment: ${workspaceFolder} seems to be the location of launch.json file. With or without /www and /app (folders do not exists there), as well as creating those folders, didn't help.

By the way, the web site is asking to move those comments to chat.

Comment: 1) *"192.168.123.11:9003 does not appear in the code netstat -abn"* It will not show the exact IP It can be `*.9003` or `0.0.0.0:9003` etc. Just check all entries where VSCode listens on. P.S. This is assuming that you are using "Listen for Xdebug" configuration, as all other from your `launch.json` work a bit differently...

Comment: 2) "* I tried setting the code pathMappings code without any success, but I'm not sure I set them correctly"* Show what you have tried. Also state 1) The local path t the project root folder. 2) The same (project root) on a NAS file system. Lets assume that you have a file called `text_xdebug.php` in the project root. You need to configure path mapping so that VSCode can transform it from full local to full remote path (by simply replacing the local mapping string by remote one)

Comment: Sorry, I phrased it unclear, port 9003 does not appear in the `netstat -abn` output at all.
Yes, I am using "Listen for Xdebug" configuration.

Comment: My pathMappings settings: 
`"pathMappings": {
"/volume1/web/loomnest.com": "${workspaceFolder}/www",
 "/app": "${workspaceFolder}/app"
}`
Copied from the example at the link you mentioned, and as stated, removing the /www and /app didn’t help

Local path: W:\loomnest.com
NAS path: /volume1/web/loomnest.com as specified in Control Panel > Shared Folders: selecting my folder > Edit > NFS Permissions: Mount path found at the bottom left corner.
${workspaceFolder} found by File > Save Workspace As… in VSCode.

Comment: *"port 9003 does not appear in the `netstat -abn` output at all."* Odd.. here is mine: https://i.imgur.com/ST3ImYH.png Double check the Firewall (just in case). Perhaps you are using different port now etc? I'm basing it all on what you have showed so far.

Comment: *"My pathMappings settings: ..."* Assuming the following info: 1) "W:\loomnest.com NAS path: /volume1/web/loomnest.com" and 2) The project is opened in VSCode from the website root folder W:\loomnest.com .. then the pathMappings should be `"pathMappings": { "/volume1/web/loomnest.com": "${workspaceFolder}" }` P.S. Can also try `${workspaceRoot}` instead of `${workspaceFolder}` -- should be the same thing though (if a workspace file is saved in the same folder ofc)

Comment: I do not know why port 9003 did not appear there, maybe the debugger was stopped and I didn't notice it, not it's there, but attached to the 127.0.0.1 IP and still didn't work, so I removed the `"hostname": "localhost"` from the configuration and now it's working :)
Thank you very much, LazyOne for the time and effort invested, definitely not lazy :)